# Engine suddenly died on uphill, then went back to life after a few tries

Tags: engine, bmw, diesel, fuel-injection

Car: BMW 318 TDS Compact. 90HP. 168.000KM

Situation: was driving a very intense uphill section at 70km/h, in 4th gear (2.000 rpm). Everything was ok. Engine sound, temperature, etc...

**Suddenly, despite my foot was pushing the Throttle at full power to stay at 2.000rpm, rpm started slowly dropping... until the engine STOPPED**

What happened ?

This indicator was on! (don't remember if blinking)

[image]

So after approximately 30 seconds, I tried starting the engine again. After a few tries the engine started, but hesitated a lot (the RPMS slowly went from 0 to 1000 rpm), and then I just let the engine heat a bit and started driving again.

Then I drove cautiously till my destination.

After opening the hood of the car, I was surprised to see that the EGR part was quite cold.

Please help me to understand what happened?

EDIT : I found there is an air bubble in the Gasoil pipe. Might that be a reason ... ?

[image]

Comment: That light looks like an injector and the "low power, revs stayed down" sounds like a limp mode.  How cold was it when this happened?  Note for answerers: some google searching makes it sound like this is a possible fuel pump or injector problem (supporting the warning light as well).

Comment: @BobCross ... At a glance, I'd think the fuel pump as well.

Comment: many thanks for the comments. I'll check the fuel pump. What I don't understand is that it works the rest of the time. The temperature (of the exterior air) is about 3 degrees centigrade.

Comment: PS : today, I had to take the same road again, and the problem happened again. It seems it occurs when the car is tilted behind, I.e. when I am climbing a hill. Then Gasoil may not come from the fuel area to the engine ?

Comment: Not knowing much about this particular vehicle, I wonder if the pickup for the fuel has become detached. This would get to a lean fuel stated if the fuel got down below where it could pick up the fuel. Don't know, so just throwing it out there.

Comment: @Paulster2: Thanks for the lead Paulster. I must add that now the car works fine, but that it can have a few issues when I go on a steep (climbing) road. Also when I start the car after a long inactivity period (1 day), it requires me to hold the switch in a "start" position for a long time ! Then the engine progressively starts ... and there a HUGE plummet of fumes gets of the exhaust pipe.

Comment: Even if the vehicle is running fine now, it doesn't sound happy.  A quick run to the garage to ask them to read the engine error codes is highly recommended.  A quick read of the BMW forums tells me that injector system problems are common on this vehicle (i.e., you're not alone and the solutions are well understood).

Comment: @BobCross : I will do that. Many thanks for the advice.

Comment: I too had the same problem. Any fix for this please let me know. For me it happens normally on normal roads but normally with long drives this shows up.

Answer (score 1):

2 options :

- the pump that pressures the gasoil into the circuit (this pump is just inside one of the rear passenger seats, just over the oil tank) is dead
- an electrical relay that activates that pump is dead.

Normally, you here a little sound that lasts for 1 or 2 seconds when you turn on your car (lights on, but engine off). Like the sound of a little motor.

When this problem exists, you don't hear that little sound anymore.

This leads your car to stall & totally get off once the diesel level dumps below 1/4 of the tank capacity. When you are near the 1/4, driving uphill, or turning very fast on the left (centrifugal force) artificially increase the effect of the problem by driving the diesel away from the conduit.

The fix is just to replace the pump or the relay that activates it.